# How to target a specific Test.toml instead of all of them with anchor test?

Tags: anchor, anchor-test, testing

Running `anchor test` in a project with multiple `Test.toml` files executes every command labeled `"test"` in every `Test.toml` `[script]` block, (and from that of the `Anchor.toml` too).

I've looked high and low, and I can't seem to find it -- is there a way to target a single `Test.toml` for execution?

It seems also scripts not named `test` can only be executed using `anchor run <script>`, which does not start a test validator. Which means I can't simply rename each script to something unique.